# Coq proof that p<q or p>=q

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove the following trivial lemma:

```
Lemma lt_or_ge: forall a b : nat,
  ((a <? b) = false) -> (b <= a).
Proof.
  intros a0 b0 H.
```

I need something like:

```
((a <? b) = false) -> (a >= b)
```

But can't seem to find it in Coq libraries.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Search` command only takes into account imported modules, meaning you need to you import `Arith` module to get access to a number of useful (and now searchable) lemmas.

A search query like the following one

```
From Coq Require Import Arith.
(* queries separated by whitespace mean boolean "and" *)
Search (_ <? _) false (_ <= _).
```

will get you what you need right away:

```
lt_or_ge: forall a b : nat, (a <? b) = false -> b <= a
Nat.ltb_ge: forall x y : nat, (x <? y) = false <-> y <= x
```

Comment: I'm writing `Require Import Coq.Arith.` but it fails with `Unable to locate library Coq.Arith.`

Comment: OK I wrote `Reqiure Import Coq.Arith.Arith` now everything works fine! thanks!

Comment: Great! Btw, the recommended way to import these days would be `From Coq Require Import Arith.`